# React Native - How to show scrollbar in TextInput on Android

Tags: android, react-native, textinput

I have a text input on android and I'd like for it to show the scroll indicator, however it never does, even when scrolling. I've seen people ask about this on ScrollView's but not on TextInput's

This functionality is not mentioned here https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput

```
        <TextInput
          ref={ref}
          textAlignVertical="top"
          margin={5}
          flex={1}
          minHeight={60}
          autoFocus={false}
          multiline={true}
          padding={2}
          maxLength={100}
          value={noteText}
          onChangeText={setNoteText}
          placeholder={`Input text here`}
        />
```

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for `multiline`. With `multiline` set to true, the box will allow multiple lines of text within the defined size of the box. After the lines exceed the size of the box, the scroll wheel will appear.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#multiline

Comment: Multiline is set to true already however the issue is that the scroll bar is not showing.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Make sure your box has a set height and width. If that doesn't work, maybe delete your node modules folder and reinstall